# Ubuntu x64 Intel

Tags: android, ubuntu, x86-64

**Доброго времени суток!**

Для компиляции Android`а( версий 2.3.* и выше ) из исходников необходимо 64-битное Linux based окружение. Сами разработчики рекомендуют использовать Ubuntu LTS 10.04( естественно 64 битную ). Но вот проблема. Все x64 версии Ubuntu для процессоров семейства AMD :( Как быть, если иметь 64-битную Ubuntu очень хочется, а камень - Intel ?

Если это уж ну никак невозможно, то был бы рад хотя бы получить совет, какие еще дистрибутивы, кроме Ubuntu, удобны для моей задачи( та, что кратно описана в самом начале ).

**Спасибо!**

Comment: AMD64 - это не процессор, и не семейство. это архитектура. Подойдет любой Intel или AMD процессор, поддерживающий х64

Answer (score 5):

> 64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop image
>
> Choose
> this to take full advantage of
> computers based on the AMD64 or EM64T
> architecture (e.g., Athlon64, Opteron,
> EM64T Xeon, Core 2). If you have a
> non-64-bit processor made by AMD, or
> if you need full support for 32-bit
> code, use the Intel x86 images
> instead.

Обратите внимание, Core 2.

**Update**

[Тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) приведен список процессоров Intel, поддерживающих архитектуру EMT64.

Comment: Да уж, к сожалению, архитектура моего процессора не Core2...все равно, спасибо)

Comment: @0xFFh, а какой процессор тогда? Может пора задуматься об апгрейде? Все-таки в паре с em64t идет и аппаратная виртуализация и она реально облегчает жизнь.

Comment: @decube, Intel Nehalem. На сколько известно, эта архитектура - преемник Core 2. Имеет ли это значение?

Comment: Ахаха! У него Нехалем, а он стесняется :)
Core i5 / Core i7 являются 64-битными процессорами. И они естественно поддерживают архитектуру `AMD64`, она же `EMT64`, она же `x86-64` (см. ссылку в ответе).

Comment: =) ок. Странно, попробую все сначала..

Answer (score 2):

Если у Вас процессор не поддерживает EMT64, то можно попробовать установить 64-битную систему в VirtualBox. Он может эмулирует 64-битное окружение даже на 32-битных машинах.

Comment: Да, видимо, все таки придется использовать системы виртуализации. В моем случае, конечно же, это не лучший вариант, но других, в общем-то, и нет. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю актуально ли но к примеру я пользуюсь именно Ubuntu

```
binliz@binliz:~$
Linux binliz 3.8.0-27-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 9 00:17:05 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
binliz@binliz:~$ sudo lshw
      *-core
           описание: Материнская плата
           продукт: P8B75-V
           производитель: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
           физический ID: 0
           версия: Rev X.0x
           серийный №: MT7026K01702455
           слот: To be filled by O.E.M.
         *-cpu
              описание: ЦПУ
              продукт: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10GHz
              производитель: Intel Corp.
```

...

Для того, чтобы не гадать будет ли стартовать 64 битная Ubuntu, хватит скачать установочный диск и запустится с него. И эта самая система сама вам скажет о своих возможностях.

Comment: Да, я, в общем-то, так и делаю. Всегда сначала загружаюсь с установочного диска, а уже потом устанавливаю Linux дистрибутив. Но проблема в том, что при попытке загрузиться с LiveCD с Ubuntu, я получаю системную ошибку при попытке отыскать операционную систему.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь ставить серверную версию или нашли где-то хост?